# (Ionic V3) MapBox not Loading for a Third Time

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, mapbox

I'm integrating MB on my Ionic 3 project.
There's a map on my 'home' page. When user touches a button another map loads which uses the Directions API and after another click by user another map is supposed to load but won't.
The map div is present on this page but the styles and js script don't seem to get applied to it.
Is there a limitation which declares you cannot load MapBox 3 times in a project or is there something from my end?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, *sigh*, the problem was I was using the same map id on all my HTML pages containing a map div, forgetting Ionic applications are called one-page-apps.
Renaming map container divs fixed it.